# How to align object below hovered menu

Tags: html, css, hover, mousehover

Under my posts I have a read more button along with a few buttons. My last button is a social share button, and when you hover over it a social share menu appears below it. The problem is that the buttons are all aligned next to each other which I want, however when you hover over the share button the share button moves up and the social share menu appears aligned with the other buttons. How could I make it so that the social share menu appears below all of the buttons and my share button always stays aligned with the other buttons? Thanks in advance. Here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5mgoktLs/2/

*I also want the share menu to be centered under the share button

Buttons before hover...

[image]

when you hover over the share button... ( I want the share button to always stay aligned with the other buttons)

[image]

html

```html
    <img class="abother-reply" src="http://amandoblogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/share-e1408475480528.png" />
  <img class="reply" src="http://amandoblogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/share-e1408475480528.png" />
<div class="wrap">

  <img class="main-share button" src="http://amandoblogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/share-e1408475480528.png" />

  <div class="share-buttons">

    <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=Love this post by @ <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this!"><img src="https://www.theclimategroup.org/sites/all/modules/custom/tcg_social_media_icons/icons/black/16x16/twitter.png"></a>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.shipwreckmuseum.com/wp-content/themes/shipwreckmuseum/assets/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook" />
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
      <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-FaD4j4FL1Bc/TuEf9aN1gEI/AAAAAAAABek/kVqztZRwJ1w/s128/Pinterest_Favicon.png" alt="Pinterest" />
    </a>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.ihatestevensinger.com/osafe_theme/images/user_content/images/icon-heart.png" alt="Heart" />
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

css

```html
.wrap:hover .share-buttons {
  display:block;
}
.share-buttons {
  display: none;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
}
.reply {
    display: inline-block;
}
.another-reply {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it's not clear, do you want the original button to stay in line like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5mgoktLs/5/ or the hover buttons to stay in line like the answer by @Pangloss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

```
.wrap:hover .share-buttons {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Updated:** If you want it centered, this is a bit hacky but it works!

```
.wrap:hover .share-buttons {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 30%);
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrap {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! Would you happen to know how I could center the share menu under the share button?

Comment: Awesome thank you! I have one last problem if your still willing to help. On my site I actually have the share button in the middle of three buttons.  The problem is that the social share menu will appear even if you didn't hover over the button. (if the mouse is a little bit to the right of the button) you can see what I mean here, I moved the social share button to the middle and even if you scroll over the last button it will still appear - https://jsfiddle.net/h8mjqsw6/  Is there a way to make it so that the menu will appear only if you scroll over the actual button space?

Comment: That's happening because your third button is inside the "wrap" div that triggers the share buttons. Move it outside the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your css to this:

```
.wrap:hover .share-buttons  {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```